# Windows Server 2016 - GPO

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm setting up a new server,I have created some groups, added some users on them and I want to provide user group name next to user during login. What group policy do I need to do that? I would like to achieve something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0nxm.png)

Answer (score 1):

A user can be member of multiple groups, Windows don't provide a built-in way to list groups in the display name.

However, you can change the [display name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-displayname) of your users in Active Directory, either manually or with a Powershell script and the [ActiveDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) module.

Here is an example that shows how to change the DisplayName with a powershell script and the [Set-ADUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps) cmdlet:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-set-ad-ds-users-display-names/